# uncaught exception: SyntaxError: missing : after property id : @(shell):1:67...... What is the error here? Any help or suggestions is welcom

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to MongoDB and when I run this code. I get that error. I don't understand how to solve this.

```
db.tours.insertMany([{name:"The seas explorer",price:497,rating:4,8},{name:"The Snow Adventurer", price:997,rating:4.9, difficulty:"easy"}])
```

Comment: Please Elaborate

Comment: When i run that above code, the get the following error : "uncaught exception: SyntaxError: missing : after property id :"

Comment: Can you provide the whole snippet of the above function?

Comment: In the first document of rating should be 4.8 not 4,8

Comment: Ohh my goodness how can i be so dumb :(

Answer (score 0):

As Jay says you have comma in a number.

https://restfulapi.net/json-data-types/

https://onecompiler.com/mongodb/3yf2c3hs3